# Could not locate the assembly "System.Fabric"

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-service-fabric

Seeing the following build warning in command prompt,

> D:\CxCache\MsBuild.Corext.14.0.23107.9\v14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Coul d not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "**System.Fabric**". Check to make sure the assembly exists
>   on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.

followed by the error,

> D:\CxCache\MsBuild.Corext.14.0.23107.9\v14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1819,5): warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "**System.Fabric**". Check to make sure the assembly exists
>   on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get
>   compilation errors.        For SearchPath
>   "{TargetFrameworkDirectory}".
>                    Considered "D:\CxCache\DotNetFxRefAssemblies.Corext.4.6.0\System.Fabric.dll", but
>   it didn't exist.
>                    Considered "D:\CxCache\DotNetFxRefAssemblies.Corext.4.6.0\System.Fabric.exe", but
>   it didn't exist.

My change,

From:
package id="Microsoft.ServiceFabric" version="5.2.207"

To:

package id="Microsoft.ServiceFabric" version="6.3.187"

I am new to Nuget and msbuild. Looking for starting pointers...Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did some research and nuget has Microsoft.ServiceFabric there are 2 ways to do this. Open the Package Manager (nuget) console, or open nuget package manager.
The Package Manager is located in visual studio (Tools > Nuget Package Manager > Package Manager) and/or around that area, that one is easy to look up. For installing you want to enter this into your package manager.

[Install-Package Microsoft.ServiceFabric -Version 7.0.466] or any version that follow in your visual studio project. Looking on nuget (dot) org you can find it easily and all the accepted versions, I already said this and I'll say it again. Be sure to be in your project when you do this and the reference will be added.